# How to setup Struts 2 within existing Eclipse by maintaining other configuration?

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2

I am a novice programmer in using [Apache Struts 2](http://struts.apache.org/) MVC Framework. I want to setup Struts 2 within my existing Eclipse IDE and I don't want to harm other different works I do in Eclipse. Here is a list of things I do in Eclipse and other related works:

1. I am currently using eclipse ide for Java SE developers.
2. Already using PDT: Eclipse PHP Development within existing eclipse for php projects.
3. Also using Eclipse CDT:C/C++ Development Tool within existing eclipse.
4. My computer contains LAMP installed with Apache2 server for web development purpose.

So, I want keep all of these things intact while setting up Struts 2 within existing eclipse. I've seen many installation guidelines for Struts 2, but they didn't clarify well about situation similar to mine.Therefore, before full installation, i want answers of these questions below:

1. Can I install Struts 2  in eclipse IDE for java SE (not EE) developers ?
2. Installing Struts 2 requires Apache Tomcat installation, will this installation create any conflict with my existing Apache 2 server (which comes with  LAMP)?

Comment: You don't install S2 into eclipse. Yes you can use S2 in standard eclipse or  in the notepad. No tomcat will not interfere with apache2 if they run on different ports. You're better off using different eclipse instances for different developments, because various plugins might interfere with each other and might slow down eclipse all together. Also you can search for some S2 eclipse plugins in the eclipse marketplace. They can help you in S2 app development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you need Eclipse for Java EE and Tomcat web server installed. There you can create a dynamic web project and use Maven to manage artifacts and download dependencies. See how to [Create Struts 2 Web Application With Artifacts In WEB-INF lib and Use Ant To Build The Application](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Create+Struts+2+Web+Application+With+Artifacts+In+WEB-INF+lib+and+Use+Ant+To+Build+The+Application)

Tomcat server by default uses port 8080, but Apache uses 80, unless you use the same port for both they won't conflict.

Comment: Very useful & correct comment.I just download eclipse ide for java EE developers and i also kept  my old eclipse ide java for SE developers.They runs separately without any error.I  download  Tomcat server that runs at port 8080 without having any conflict with Apache server that runs at port 80.Finally  Struts 2 is working on my computer.Thanks