# Struts2 - HTTP Status 404 - /struts2Test/testAction.action

Tags: jsp, struts2, http-status-code-404

I am new to struts. I am trying to understand how it, I've seen lot of tutorials and solutions but nothing can help solve my error. Could you please help me understand where I went wrong and what needs to be corrected. Below is my code.

My web.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
               http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
              <display-name>struts2Test</display-name>
              <welcome-file-list>
                <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
              </welcome-file-list>
             <filter>
              <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
              <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter- 
 class>
             </filter>
             <filter-mapping>
              <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
              <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
             </filter-mapping>
            </web-app>
```

my struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="test" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="testAction" class="TestAction">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

my action class

```
public class TestAction {
    public String execute() {
        System.out.println("in execute method");
        return "success";
    }
}
```

my success jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>success</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

my error jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
            pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>error.jsp</h1>
        </body>
        </html>
```

[image]

my path

[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32445402/573032) answer will be useful if you are using Eclipse. It is a tutorial for newbies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the S2 config you indicate your JSP files are at the root of the web content. They're not, they're in the `WEB-INF` directory, so your results should reflect that, e.g.,

```
<result name="success">/WEB-INF/success.jsp</result>
```

It's also not clear how you're deploying the app, e.g., the app context may or may not be `struts2Test` so you'll need to figure that out as well.

Comment: Actually i didnt add any to the libraries and when i added it worked fine. i ll also try out what you have mentioned. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Your application is not able to access the URL because you have not extended the **ActionSupport** class for your action class. Try with extending it.