# Struts2 - Tomcat - Intellij

Tags: web, tomcat, intellij-idea, struts2

I'm following a course of struts2 using Eclipse.
I have intellij ultimate and i'm more confident with this.
How can i create the corresponding of Eclipe's Dynamic Web Project with Inellij?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Why not to import existing project?

Comment: How can i importa an existing project if i dont have one?

Comment: Isn't it covered by the tutorial you are following? Here's link to another [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32445402/573032) from oficial resources.

Comment: It doesn't seem that you are confident with the IDE you are limiting yourself with. Otherwise you wouldn't ask that. Please use Stack Overflow for technical questions only.

Comment: Dear @howlger
Being confident doesn't mean to know everything.
Being confident means that i used a lot more intellij and the ui of eclipse doesn't fit me.

Comment: Dear @RomanC
Thanks for linking to me that article, hopes it will help me! :)

Comment: Better choose the tools to suit your needs rather than which UI you like better. But the point is that such questions should be better asked e.g. at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-web-application-support.html, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/deploying-a-web-app-into-an-app-server-container.html, etc. There are many tutorials/docs/etc for creating web apps in IntelliJ.